# spyder: Create new project from existing directory

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, spyder

I'm encountering a problem using spyder (I'm novice):

1. Projects --> New Project...
2. The project form appears
3. I select "Existing directory"

I can't edit both *Project name* and *Location*

To be sure of the issue I've re-install conda and update all the packages. Currently I'm using the following versions:

- conda:  4.8.3
- spyder: 4.1.2
- spyder-kernels: 1.9.0

I've tried also to create new conda *venv* but I got the same problem.

I'm installed conda on NeonKde a linux distribution ubuntu based (18.04) kerner: 5.3.0-46-generic

Here i've provided a screenshot: [New project dialog form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPJTf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Spyder 4.0.1. Spyder doesn't allow naming a project in existing directory because it does not do anything. I think because this functionality is for creating a new folder path if you don't want to use current directory. So if you want to  create a new project(folder), choose New Directory>Project Name or simply try opening a new file
from File options.

Comment: Hi Dhruv, thank you for your reply.
I can't agree with you. The option to create a project from existing directory is enabled and it must work. Otherwise the option should not be displayed. There are other strange behaviours in spyder I can't understand and all of them concern paths. I'm going to open an issue on git project.